# How to make sure my variables are initialised when used by different routes?

Tags: node.js, async-await, gitlab-ci, webhooks

My API has 2 different routes :

- 1 for the end user where they post the data they want and then trigger GitLab pipelines where I fetch the triggered pipeline id and the job id's within the pipeline.
- 1 is for the GitLab webhook I've integrated.

I got 2 variables : `pipelineId` and `jobId`. They're global variables since I use them in both routes. They are both initially empty, but then initialised in the first route.

The first route fetches them within the response body after the trigger and I want to use them to fetch a specific job's logs in the 2nd route. However, I end up with empty variables since both routes are executing themselves in parallel. Now, my question is how to make sure my variables are initialised by the 1st route when used in the 2nd route.

This is the code I'm working on :

```
const axios = require('axios');
const api = require('lambda-api')();
let FormData = require('form-data');

let PROJECT_ID_CREATE = process.env.PROJECT_ID_CREATE
let PROJECT_ID_DESTROY = process.env.PROJECT_ID_DESTROY
let CREATE_TOKEN = process.env.CREATE_TOKEN
let DESTROY_TOKEN = process.env.DESTROY_TOKEN
let PRIVATE_TOKEN = process.env.PRIVATE_TOKEN
let pipelineId = ""
let jobId = ""
let ec2InstanceLink = ""
let config = ""
// First route where the end user posts their data
api.post('/api-gitlab-launcher/create', async (lambdaRequest, res) => {
        //Trigger pipelines
        await axios.post(`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID_CREATE}/trigger/pipeline?token=${CREATE_TOKEN}&ref=terraform-v1-mirror`)
            .then(async (gitlabPOSTResponse) => {
                    pipelineId = gitlabPOSTResponse.data.id
                    console.log(`pipeline_id = ${pipelineId}`)
                }, (error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            )

        config = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID_CREATE}/pipelines/${pipelineId}/jobs`,
            headers: {
                "PRIVATE-TOKEN": PRIVATE_TOKEN
            }
        }
        //Get Job Id
        await axios(config)
            .then(async (gitlabGETResponse) => {
                    for (let gitlabGETResponseKey in gitlabGETResponse.data) {
                        if (gitlabGETResponse.data[gitlabGETResponseKey].name === 'apply') {
                            jobId = JSON.stringify(gitlabGETResponse.data[gitlabGETResponseKey].id);
                            console.log(`Job id : ${JSON.stringify(gitlabGETResponse.data[gitlabGETResponseKey].id)}`)
                        }
                    }
                }, (error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            )
        config = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID_CREATE}/jobs/${jobId}`,
            headers: {
                "PRIVATE-TOKEN": PRIVATE_TOKEN
            }
        }
        //Get Job Logs using Job Id
        await axios(config)
            .then((getJobLogsResponse) => {
                    let jobLog = JSON.stringify(getJobLogsResponse.data)
                    ec2InstanceLink = jobLog.match('https:(...)*\.(...)*\.com\:8443')
                    console.log(`Link in Job Log : ${ec2InstanceLink}`)
                }
            )

        /*let data = new FormData();
        data.append('token', DESTROY_TOKEN);
        data.append('ref', 'terraform-v1');
        data.append('variables[LAST_PIPELINE_ID]', pipelineId);

        config = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID_DESTROY}/trigger/pipeline`,
            data: data,
            headers: {
                ...data.getHeaders()
            }
        }
        await axios(config)
            .then(
                () => {
                    console.log("Resources destroyed.")
                }, (error) => {
                    console.log(`error : ${error}`)
                }
            )*/
    }
)
// 2nd route where the gitlab webhook posts the job events
api.post('/api-gitlab-launcher/gitlab-webhook', async (gitlabRequest, res) => {
        if (pipelineId != '') {
            if (gitlabRequest.body["pipeline_id"] === pipelineId) {
                if (gitlabRequest.body["build_id"] === jobId) {
                    if (gitlabRequest.body["build_status"] === 'success') {
                        config = {
                            method: 'GET',
                            url: `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID_CREATE}/jobs/${jobId}`,
                            headers: {
                                "PRIVATE-TOKEN": PRIVATE_TOKEN
                            }
                        }
                        //Get Job Logs using Job Id
                        await axios(config)
                            .then((getJobLogsRequest) => {
                                    let jobLog = JSON.stringify(getJobLogsRequest.data)
                                    //ec2InstanceLink = jobLog.match('https:(...)*\.(...)*\.com\:8443')
                                    console.log(`Link in Job Log : ${jobLog}`)
                                }
                            )
                    } else {
                        console.log("wrong status")
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log(`wrong job job_id in log : ${gitlabRequest.body["build_id"]} and my job_id : ${jobId}`)
                }
            } else {
                console.log(`wrong pipeline pipeline_id in log : ${gitlabRequest.body["pipeline_id"]} and my pipeline_id : ${pipelineId}`)
            }
        }
    }
)

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    return await api.run(event, context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the second call depends on information retrieved from the first call, you need to chain them, so that they execute in order, instead of in parallel.

For example, wrap call #2 inside a function and call that function from the complete handler (where you set the pipelineId).

Comment: I can't wrap the second call in the 1st one, or else the route isn't available anymore

Comment: Then it's the other way around: you should execute whatever the second call depends on, when the second call gets executed. The second call should fetch the pipelineId as part of its own logic since it needs to be able to run independently.